# Envío dos fechas por medio de una función de JavaScriptp por JQuery y el controller solo recibe un parámetro

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Lo que quiero hacer es un Modal donde se pueda seleccionar un rango de fechas para un reporte por medio de un `Stored Procedure`.

Este es mi código de JavaScript:

```
function Generar() {
    var Rango = { "Date": "", "Date2": "" };
    var Date = $('#Date').val();
    var Date2 = $('#Date2').val();
    var url ="@Url.Action("Reporte", "Triturations", new { Date = "param-Date",Date2 = "param-Date2"})";
    url = url.replace("param-Date", encodeURIComponent(Date))
   alert( url = url.replace("param-Date2", encodeURIComponent(Date2)));
    location.href = url;
}
```

Este es mi código HTML:

```
<label for="Date" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fecha Inicial</label>
                <input type="datetime" id="Date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" class="form-control daterangepicker" form="modalform" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
                <label for="Date2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fecha Final</label>
                <input type="datetime" id="Date2" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" class="form-control daterangepicker" form="modalform" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

Y este mi código C# en el Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Reporte(DateTime? Date,DateTime? Date2)
    {
        //var Date = form["Date"];
        //var Date2 = form["Date2"];
        //DateTime T1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
        //DateTime T2 = Convert.ToDateTime(Date2);

        DateTime T1 = Date.Value;
        DateTime T2 = Date2.Value;

        MisEntities db = new MisEntities();
        var query = db.spu_rep_Trituracion(T1, T2).ToList();
        Reporte_Tri rpt = new Reporte_Tri();
        rpt.Load();
        rpt.SetDataSource(query);
        Stream s = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        return File(s, "application/pdf");

    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál de las dos fechas está realmente obteniendo el valor?

Comment: La primera, el segundo lo recibe como nulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` es una reservada para **JavaScript**, intenta ponerle otro nombre como `Date1`, por ejemplo.

Comment: Negativo Hermano y gracias por el aporte, le puse un `alert()` al url y me dio como resultado esta ruta (/Triturations/Reporte?Date1=10%2F01%2F2016&amp;Date2=10%2F31%2F2016) , no se si de ahi pueda venir el problema.

Comment: De acuerdo bro, mira, checando los parámetros que envias estás enviando lo siguiente: **Date1=10012016&Date2=103‌​12016** si logras ver la variable Date2 tiene un formato de MM/dd/aaaa y el controller no lo está interpretando porque seguramente espera un formato dd/MM/aaa

Comment: Bro, encontré el problema no era el que me dijiste pero me sirvió para encontrarlo, [/Triturations/Reporte?Date1=10%2F01%2F2016&amp;Date2=10%2F3‌​1%2F2016], estos caracteres **"amp;"** se los quite del url y funciono.

Comment: Por cierto muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente, aunque de cierta forma es correcto que tenga esos caracteres ya que se codifican las cadenas enviadas a modo de seguridad en el envío de alguna petición. Pero qué bueno que ya quedó, un saludo bro!